# can t import HTTP module on client in meteor 1.3

Tags: http, meteor, reactjs

i use react on meteor 1.3 and want to directly upload big files from the client to a file storage API (www.backblaze.com)

importing HTTP on the server works,
but it does not work on the client

```
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';
```

i get the error message on the client:
"Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'meteor/http'" on install.js:78

but it works on the server (if the client API calls are commented out), where i import it the same way and make successful API calls.

the documentation indicates that it can be used client and server side:
http://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html

i use (osx chrome Version 50.0.2661.102) on the client side

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

after re-installing the HTTP package, the import works for client and sever.